# Tomcat error in dspace

Tags: tomcat, dspace

Tomcat does not work properly in DSpace 6.2 installation. This problem occurred after a power failure of the server.
/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out shows following errors.

```
18-Jul-2018 17:26:28.688 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying configuration descriptor [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/jspui.xml]
18-Jul-2018 17:26:28.699 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.fatalError Parse Fatal Error at line 2 column 6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
18-Jul-2018 17:26:28.703 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying configuration descriptor [/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/jspui.xml]
 WARN [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dspace.eventService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.dspace.services.EventService org.dspace.utils.DSpace.getEventService()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: DSpace kernel cannot be null
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dspace.eventService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.dspace.services.EventService org.dspace.utils.DSpace.getEventService()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: DSpace kernel cannot be null*
```

The /opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/jspui.xml file is as follows.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Context
    docBase="[dspace]/webapps/jspui"
    reloadable="true"
    cachingAllowed="false"/>*
```

But the Tomcat service is running,

```
 systemctl status tomcat
● tomcat.service - SYSV: Tomcat Start/Shutdown script
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-07-18 17:26:27 +0530; 38min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 1711 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1733 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
           └─1742 /opt/jdk1.8.0_144/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=...

Jul 18 17:26:27 repo.pgim.cmb.ac.lk systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Tomcat Start/Shutdown script...
Jul 18 17:26:27 repo.pgim.cmb.ac.lk tomcat[1733]: Tomcat started.
Jul 18 17:26:27 repo.pgim.cmb.ac.lk systemd[1]: Started SYSV: Tomcat Start/Shutdown script.
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: In docBase="[dspace]/webapps/jspui", "[dspace]" must be a real path.  

How was the service started before the power failure?

Comment: I have changed docBase="[dspace]/webapps/jspui" to docBase="/opt/tomcat/webapps/jspui", but did not worked. It was started with 'systemctl start tomcat' command long time back. Worked well till the power failure.

Comment: This issue may be difficult to troubleshoot on Stack Overflow.  I recommend that you go to one of the DSpace support channels.  https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/Support